# How to multiply entries of a column sequentially and take the average

Tags: awk

I have a column of data which looks like this:

```
6.14001 
6.13606 
6.13752 
6.12979 
6.13292 
6.13987 
6.13182 
6.13528 
6.13161 
6.13784 
6.13439 
6.13448 
6.13165 
6.13396 
6.13786 
6.13502
```

How can I do the following: multiply the entries in a consecutive way (1 *2)+(2 * 3)+(3 * 4) ...) and take the average ...and then start the multiplication from 2 (2 * 3)+(3 * 4) + (4 * 5 ) and take this average then from 3 and so on. Is it possible to do this with awk?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and show us your code?

Comment: Are you looking to compute the sum to the end of the list each time, or in groups of 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you save numbers in array, you can do the things you want:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{
    for(i=1;i<NR;i++){
        s[i]=a[i]*a[i+1]
        t+=s[i]
    }
    for(i=NR-1;i>0;i--){t-=s[NR-1-i];printf "%d: %.5f\n",++x, t/i}
}' file
```

output with your data:

```
1: 37.63623
2: 37.63343
3: 37.63137
4: 37.63217
5: 37.63569
6: 37.63373
7: 37.63208
8: 37.63353
9: 37.63559
10: 37.63571
11: 37.63247
12: 37.63277
13: 37.63886
14: 37.65264
15: 37.65589
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $(grep -c ^ file))
do
  tail -n +$i file | awk 'a{s+=a*$1} !a{a=$1} END{printf "%f\n", s/(NR-1)}'
done
```

It gives the following output:

```
37.666943
37.642103
37.649667
37.604576
37.624784
37.664363
37.616733
37.637496
37.617603
37.652948
37.631992
37.632719
37.621433
37.640678
37.655894
-nan
```

**Explanation:**

- `for i in $(seq 1 $(grep -c ^ file))`: a loop from 1 to the number of lines in the file
- `tail -n +$i file`: skip the first `$i` lines
- `awk 'a{s+=a*$1} !a{a=$1}`: do the calculations and ...
- `END{printf "%f\n", s/(NR-1)}'`: ... print the average at the end